# Как выровнять форму авторизации по центру с табами?

Tags: css, bootstrap, form, bootstrap4

Суть в чем. Есть форма. Но форма не простая, а с табами. С табами Авторизация, Регистрация, Правила.

В гугле нашел как выровнять блок на центру страницы. Но вот фигня в том что если переключать табы (а они разной высоты) то блок меняет размер.

Увидеть это можно тут: https://www.codeply.com/go/zjrSL7SkaE

Если вы нажмете на Правила, то форма станет выше и заголовки табов прыгают вверх. То бишь юзеру придется гонятся за блоком что бы переключить вкладку.

Как можно сделать так что бы форма оставалась на месте (то бишь по центру), но высота менялась вниз страницы.

Может вообще по другому сделать надо.

Answer (score 0):

Чтобы получить то что Вы хотите, надо убрать выравнивание по вертикали, и назначить отступ сверху в пикселях, а ещё лучше в процентах.

```
.h-100 {
    margin-top: 5%;
}
```

Это исправленная тринадцатая строка Вашего html.

```
<div class="row justify-content-center text-center align-middle h-100">
```

Comment: Спасибо за подсказку, но называть класс не семантичным для него именем как-то не очень.

Comment: Это просто пример, естественно без семантики. Я вписал свойство первому попавшемуся классу, из тех что уже есть.

Comment: Кстати, может быть хорошо указать отступ в "vh" или задать calc (50vh - 100px). Сто пикселей это для примера.